# Enable Fingerprint but still set Require Sign in to NEVER

Tags: windows-10, sleep, login, fingerprint

Just installed Windows 10 Pro 22H2.

OK maybe this makes no sense what I am trying to do but...
Can I set up Windows Hello Fingerprint AND set "Require sign-in" to NEVER?
My question is basically the opposite of [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1737726/1064544).

Currently with a fingerprint set up the dropdown menu where you can specify the "Require Sign in" options is grayed out and is stuck on "Every Time" and there is text in red: *"Windows Hello is preventing some options from being shown"*.

So in order to disable the requirement to sign in after Windows awakes from sleep I am not permitted to set up a fingerprint login method?

Comment: That may be related to a BIOS password security settings (not certain). I have one Lenovo laptop where I cannot change this setting (i did change it over a year ago and changed it back) and an older Lenovo laptop where I can still change this setting.  I am looking around still.

Comment: @John That's really helpful thanks. I am actually using a Lenovo E14 2nd Gen. I'll check the BIOS settings.

Comment: I think you can remove your fingerprint (so no Windows Hello) and restart, Then you should be able to set to NEVER.   Then add your fingerprint again.

Answer (score 0):

My laptop is a Lenovo E14 Gen 2.

I removed my fingerprint, and was straight away able to set `Require sign-in` to NEVER. However when I rebooted and went back to the Accounts > Sign-in options the "Require sign-in" drop down menu was back to grayed out and stuck on "Every Time" again. I confirmed by putting the laptop to sleep and was required to sign-in again.

The solution (suggested by @John) was in the Lenovo BIOS. I changed the `Sleep state` from `Windows and Linux` to `Linux 3`. Then after rebooting the "Require sign-in" dropdown has the options "NEVER" and "When PC wakes from Sleep". I could choose "Never", put the laptop to sleep and when I woke it up was NOT required to sign in.

When the Lenovo BIOS "Sleep State" is set to `Windows and Linux`, and you have configured a fingerprint in Windows, it will not let you select an option for the "Require sign-in" in Settings > Accounts > Sign in Options. Instead that drop down menu is grayed out and is stuck on "Every Time".

Comment: The reason I went back to the default way (sign in every time) is that I DO wish to sign in after the computer comes out of Suspend.  There is no good overall way to get what you want on a modern laptop

Answer (score 0):

Newer computers with newer BIOS (UEFI) grey out the setting to never sign in after away for a while is now set to ALWAYS. This seems to be true for modern computers, up to date Windows and newer BIOS (UEFI).

You can remove the fingerprint (not a good solution) or change BIOS settings to change this setting.

However, with these modern computers, setting sign in to NEVER also means that the computer will not require sign in after coming out of suspend. I regard this as a security risk, especially in a public or work setting, and I went back to the default way.

There is no setting (true of older computers) that allow NEVER sign in after being away for a while, but ALWAYS sign in after coming out of suspend.

Newer fingerprint drivers mean I am 80+ % successful with fingerprint login where the success rate was under 30% a couple of years ago.

So with improvements in Windows Hello, the new way of always require Windows Hello after being away for a while or coming out of suspend works very well (not perfect - just very well).

In the last 12 months, and I assume going forward, Windows Hello is working well enough to use the default "Always sign in after being away for a while"